# Changing addon folder name

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

how can i change the name of an addon folder?

If i change it directly in Blenders Addon folder under "C:\Users\timma\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons" then Blender get out an error message that it can´t find the script anymore. So what would i have to change also?

The addon is called "Turbo Render" with a space in between and i have to remove the space so that it can be used without problems in command rendering.

This is the error message i get if i remove the space in the name:
[image]

It´s automatically deactivated and says that it missing the script files.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Are you developing that addon?

Comment: No unfortunately not. The developer can´t give me support for that at the moment because background rendering isn´t oficially supported yet but i know how it works if i only could change the name.

Comment: Please share the error message

Comment: I updated the question with a picture :)

Comment: You haven't changed the name, you changed the category

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the folder name shouldn't cause any issue.

The issue you are having is that Blender is trying to look for an addon in a folder that doesn't exist anymore. But if you look in your screenshot, you can see the same addon found in the newly named folder. Disable the old one and enable the new one instead.

Comment: Ooh that´s right. I only had to disable the old one and it´s gone. Thanks!